# how to give animation on react app when change routes for react router DOM version 6.14.0

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, css-animations

I am trying to gave a smooth transition on pages when I change the routes. But can't find any idea.

I am trying to gave a smooth transition on pages when I change the routes. But can't find any idea
what should I do? How can I add this?

Comment: You can use `Framer-motion` package to do this. Check this video on YouTube, to get idea on how to do this
https://youtu.be/FdrEjwymzdY

Answer (score 0):

There are few packages available. You can explore [React Router's Animated Transition](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/animated-transitions)  OR another most used package [framer-motion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/framer-motion)